# Ether.Camp web3 js interact with contract - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: solidity, ether, javascript, ether-camp, ethereum-studio

I have a working contract that I made in ether.camp with solidity, it functions as desired through the IDE contract interface and now I am trying to tie it into an html GUI with web3.

To this end I have been following a series of tutorials, but as far as I can see - what I am doing should be working but it looks like it is not connecting to the contract?

Html:

```
<form>
   <button id="call"  type="submit">Call</button>
</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="dist/app.js"></script>
```

app.js

```
var async = require('async');
var Web3 = require('web3');
var ethTx = require('ethereumjs-tx');
var SolidityFunction = require('web3/lib/web3/function');

var abi = [{
    "name": "removeElement(address)",
    "type": "function",
    "inputs": [
    {
        "name": "key",
        "type": "address"
    }
    ]
}];

var sandboxId = '<my sandbox id>';
var url = 'https://<my user>.by.ether.camp:8555/sandbox/' + sandboxId;
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(url));

web3.eth.defaultAccount = '0xdedb49385ad5b94a16f236a6890cf9e0b1e30392';

$( "button" ).click(function() {
    alert("button was clicked"); //just checking the jquery was working 
    var contract = web3.eth.contract(abi).at('0x17956ba5f4291844bc25aedb27e69bc11b5bda39'); //The contract address as per the ethercamp IDE
    contract.call().removeElement("0x2adc25665018aa1fe0e6bc666dac8fc2697ff9ba");
});
```

The `removeElement(address key)` function in the contract works absolutley fine from the IDE. I suspect the above code is not actually 'connecting' to the contract? Wish I could be more detailed but I'm not sure whats not working here

Thank you!

Comment: `contract.call().removeElement("0x2ad...");` looks strange to me. I am more used to seeing `contract.removeElement.call("0x2ad...");` or `contract.removeElement("0x2ad...");`.

Comment: I will try without `call()` - repositioning it still seems to do nothing :(

Comment: Removing `call()` does not seem to work. I get the `alertbox` fine showing the button click is being triggered but nothing happens to the contract. Doing the exact same `removeElement` in the IDE works - just not from web3

Comment: Open your browser console, type `var contract = web3.eth.contract(abi).at('0x179...');` then `contract.removeElement()` and see what comes out.

Comment: Okay I get `ReferenceError: web3 is not defined` but we can see above that I am ?

Comment: I am surprised how you call a NodeJS way `var Web3 = require('web3');` in the browser.

Comment: How would you usually acheive what I am trying to do? Do you have a link to best practice? Many thanks

Comment: Get the web3.js file from https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API and include it as a script in your html.

Comment: Do you see any error messages in the browser console?

When you click on the button do you see the transaction in the [transactions dialog](http://image.prntscr.com/image/6711f5b726c04dc89fe9714c2f3dc741.png) of the IDE?

The code is built by browserify with gulp, that's why it uses CommonJS require. If you want to use web3 from the console, add `window.web3 = web3;`

Comment: Hi Alex,  nothing appears on the transactions dialog when I try and interact with contract using the button. (I modified the code as below by removing call() ). There is 1 error on the console when I click the button and after the alertbox. critical or not?
`TypeError: json.outputs is undefined
[313]</SolidityFunction()
app.js:30314
[307]</addFunctionsToContract/<()
app.js:29204
map()
self-hosted
[307]</addFunctionsToContract()
app.js:29201
[307]</ContractFactory.prototype.at()
app.js:29400
[226]</<()
app.js:23346
n.event.dispatch()
jquery-2.2.1.min.js:3
n.event.add/r.handle()`

Comment: Does that JSON error hint at a malformed abi?

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to ask for details, but I can't post comments.

1. It should be `contract.removeElement("0x2adc25665018aa1fe0e6bc666dac8fc2697ff9ba")`
2. Do you see any error messages in the browser console?
3. When you click on the button do you see the transaction in [the transactions dialog](http://image.prntscr.com/image/6711f5b726c04dc89fe9714c2f3dc741.png) of the IDE?
4. The code is built by browserify with gulp, that's why it uses CommonJS require. If you want to use web3 from the console, add `window.web3 = web3;`

Comment: I've upvoted and now you have enough reputation to post comments. Please start posting comments and then edit this to be a [full, valid, answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). Thanks

Comment: @eth thanks! I'll change it when I have more details.